# How to limit rows in PostgreSQL SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

What's the equivalent to SQL Server's `TOP` or DB2's `FETCH FIRST` or mySQL's `LIMIT` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: How funny...I *just* wanted to know this yesterday!  (of course, now I don't need to know any more, but I'll vote you up anyway since I could have used it then.)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use [LIMIT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) just like in MySQL, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: As suggested by mongotop, to avoid unpredictable results, you need to use an ORDER BY clause.
See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html

Answer (score 38):

You could always add the `OFFSET` clause along with `LIMIT` clause.

You may need to pick up a set of records from a particular offset. Here is an example which picks up 3 records starting from 3rd position:

```
testdb=# SELECT * FROM COMPANY LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2;
```

This would produce the following result:

```
 id | name  | age | address   | salary
----+-------+-----+-----------+--------
  3 | Teddy |  23 | Norway    |  20000
  4 | Mark  |  25 | Rich-Mond |  65000
  5 | David |  27 | Texas     |  85000
```

Full explanation and more examples check [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_limit_clause.htm)

Comment: When using LIMIT, it is important to use an ORDER BY clause that constrains the result rows into a unique order. Otherwise you will get an unpredictable subset of the query's rows (from documentation).

Answer (score 14):

On PostgreSQL, there are two ways to achieve this goal.

### SQL Standard

The first option is to use the SQL:2008 standard way of limiting a result set using the [`FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY`](https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-query-limit-top-n-rows/) syntax:

```
SELECT
    title
FROM
    post
ORDER BY
    id DESC
FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY
```

> The SQL:2008 standard syntax is supported since PostgreSQL 8.4.

### PostgreSQL 8.3 or older

For PostgreSQL 8.3 or older versions, you need the LIMIT clause to restrict the result set size:

```
SELECT
    title
FROM
    post
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`LIMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) clause or `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS`

Answer (score 8):

Apart from limit you could use Fetch First as well. Your question already had the answer

```
Select * from users FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select 10 students skipping the top 3, (hence fetching students of rank 4 to 13 inclusive)  from a table ordered by a rank column for example, you'd use:

`SELECT * FROM STUDENTS ORDER BY rank asc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 3;`

If you just want the top 10, you'd omit OFFSET:
`SELECT * FROM STUDENTS ORDER BY rank asc LIMIT 10;`