# Retrieving "pages" with some number of rows using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

In PostgreSQL: To retrieve 100 rows using an SQL query we can use LIMIT 100.
Is there a way to retrieve first 100 rows and later the next 100  like doing some kind of pagination? i.e.

if I do something like:

```
SELECT ..... LIMIT 100;
```

and later execute a command like:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 100
```

I could get the next 100 rows to the previous retrieval of 100 rows and so on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit rows in PostgreSQL SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133944/how-to-limit-rows-in-postgresql-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use limit combined with offset. You can find more details [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/queries-limit.html)

```
select * from table LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100*0 --first 100
select * from table LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100*1 --second 100
```